# Expand an array from existing array?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I have an array (`[1, 3]`) which contains the index to change the value of the `key` to `false`

Is there any good way to improve this code, so I dont have to specify the default value as shown in variable `b`?

This is because the default array of objects could be huge, (the code below is a simplified problem from my application..)

```
//Specify default value
const b = [
  { key: true },
  { key: true },
  { key: true },
  { key: true },
  { key: true }
]

[1, 3].forEach((x) => {
  b[x].key = false;
})
```

Comment: To better understand the question, do you need each element in `b` to be unique? Also, if you don't specify the default value in `b`, where are those value come from? You may need to different solution depends on your situation.

Comment: Could you better explain the concrete problem you're trying to solve?  I'm not sure your existing usage of data structures makes sense.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? Are you trying to optimize the definition of `b`? How many elements should it have?

Comment: What do you mean by "Expand an array"? Where is an array expanded at `javascript` at Question? `javascript` at Question appears to only set property and value of object? _"This is because the default array of objects could be huge"_ Do you create array of objects, or  retrieve array from an external resource? Do original objects already have `key` set?

Answer (score 1):

> ***"Is there any good way to improve this code, so I don't have to specify the default value as shown in variable b? This is because the default array of objects could be huge"***

My interpretation of your question is as follows: "How can I create a potentially huge array of objects, where all default to `{key: true}` *except* for those at the indices specified in another array, which should be `{key: false}`?" I'm assuming you know at the time how many objects you want in total.

It's hard to say what is "best" given that you've simplified things for purposes of the question. I suspect maybe there's a more appropriate data structure than what you've shown for `b`, but with no further information about your real code there's no point in me guessing.

So, to create an array of objects where all objects default to the same `key` value, rather than a potentially "huge" array literal you can just use a loop:

```
const b = new Array(desiredNumberOfObjects)
for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
  b[i] = { key: true }
```

...and then run your existing `[1, 3].forEach(...)` to set the required items to `false`.

That would be reasonably efficient because it only loops through the main `b` array and the exceptions array once each.

Comment: _"...and then run your existing `[1, 3].forEach(...)` to set the required items to `false`"_ If interpret Question correctly, two loops are not necessary to set `Boolean` value.

Comment: @guest271314 - Obviously it is simple to code with `b[i] = { key: exceptions.includes(i) }` (or `.indexOf(i)>-1`), but doing a lookup on every iteration seems inefficient to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "main loop"? OP describes beginning with "default array of objects". Only one loop should be necessary to set a specific property of each object to `Boolean` `true` or `false`.

Comment: @guest271314 - Sorry, I edited my comment. Anyway, by "main loop" I meant the `for` loop that I used to create all the objects. The OP seemed to be asking for a way to create that default array of objects without listing them all out in an object literal, and then the second array `[1,3]` listed the indices of exceptions to the default. I didn't want to do a lookup into that `[1,3]` array every time I created an object - it seemed more efficient to go back afterwards with a second loop to set those exceptions to `false`.

Comment: _"The OP seemed to be asking for a way to create that default array of objects"_ As interpreted Question here, OP gets an array of objects then attempts to set property of objects to `true` or `false`. "could be huge" was clue that array of "default objects" is not created by OP. Though you could be correct. Question is not clear as to how "default array of objects" is created, or retrieved.

Comment: @guest271314 - Sure, I might have misinterpreted, though I just reread it and I still read it the same way. I'll add a note to my answer to clarify my interpretation of the question so that at least people reading my answer will understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Your Answer is clear as to what your implementation suggests, based on your interpretation of Question. Question is not clear, from perspective here, as to how "default array of objects" is derived. Perhaps OP will chime in to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
//Specify default value
const b = [];

[1, 3].forEach((x) => {
  if (b[x]) {
    b[x].key = false;
  } else {
    b[x] = { key: false };
  }
})

console.log(b);
```

Not that the values in between will be undefined. If that's a problem I'd suggest making a function to check the value like so:

```
var something = b[x] ? b[x].key : true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how big the array should be. Let's say it's 6. Then you can initialize the array with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a `mapFn` argument:

```js
const b = Array.from(Array(6), () => ({key: true}));

[1, 3].forEach(x => b[x].key = false);

console.log(b);
```

You might be tempted to use `fill`:

```
Array(6).fill({key: true})
```

but this will not work as expected, since the same object will be placed at each position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can store property name to set at a variable; use `Array.prototype.entries()` to iterate index and value of array at `for..of` loop, set value of property at object to `Boolean` return value of `.indexOf()` called on array of indexes.

```js
const arr = [
  { a: 1 },
  { b: 2 },
  { c: 3 },
  { d: 4 },
  { e: 5 }
];

let [indexes, prop] = [[1, 3], `key`];

for (let [key, value] of arr.entries()) value[prop] = indexes.indexOf(key) > -1;

console.log(arr);
```